# Origin of "If I've told you once I've told you a thousand times"

Tags: etymology, idioms

I've searched the web and found only definitions and paltry speculation as to the origin of this scolding phrase. How did it get put together this illogical way? Are there tacet words in the phrase that, if said, would make it seem more logical, such as

> If I've told you once, I [might as
>   well] have told you a thousand times
>   [for all the good it did].

Where does this phrase originate, and how did it end up getting phrased that way?

Comment: This reminds me of a similar question already asked.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: link or it didn't happen. (^_^)

Comment: @RegDwight It is a similar question about "if she is 1 inch tall, she is 5' 8" tall."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Origin of "he's 6 feet tall if he's an inch"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14216/origin-of-hes-6-feet-tall-if-hes-an-inch)

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14216/origin-of-hes-6-feet-tall-if-hes-an-inch, also some random conversation: http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/29/messages/241.html

Comment: Yep, it's a dupe, but one that's a bit hard to search for directly. So now what do I do with this question? Delete it?</meta>

Comment: Can such a natural turn of phrase really be the subject of an inquiry into its origins? "I've said it a dozen times" isn't exactly unknown, and if you Google "told you [number] times* you'll get at least 50,000 for every one of "ten", "a dozen", "twenty", "fifty", "a hundred", "a million" and doubtless many others that I can't be bothered with. It's just a standard speech device that people reinvent repeatedly with whatever number comes to mind.

Comment: Why you say this is a dupe?

Comment: @Cawas: _Dupe_ is short for duplicate, as in the question was asked already by someone else. But I'm not sure that's true.

Comment: @Callithumpian lol thanks, but I'm just wondering *why* dude, not "what does dupe mean"! :P

Comment: @Cawas: OK, I wasn't sure. And I agree, I don't think it's a dupe.

Comment: @Callithumpian given that and your mistaken edit that I didn't get the time to even read, I'd say you must be drunk! :D

Comment: If I've told you once, I've told you a thousand times: Don't use hyperbole!

Comment: Sorry, kojiro; there's nothing illogical about that, nor is it strange in English. Why would a direct translation seem strange in your own language, please?

I don’t think “tacet (nor tacit)” is what you meant. I do think your phrase “If I've told you once, I [might as well] have told you a thousand times [for all the good it did]” is a very good explanation and that’s not the point, is it?

While no-one now is likely to remember the origin, the meaning of the phrase is just as you suggested and the standard expression needs no justification.

Comment: English is my first language. I asked this question seven years ago, so my motivations at the time are history, but I still think it’s an interesting and illogical idiom. First, it’s straightforwardly illogical: If I’ve told you once, of course I haven’t told you a thousand times. But even the tacit _might as well_ explanation seems unsatisfactory to me, since telling someone a thing once isn’t that frustrating and is not at all similar to telling them many, many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about "thousands" of instances of its usage? I can't resist the irony! (Add your contribution!)

> - If I've told you once, [please consider] I've told you a thousand times. - just now
> - [If I've Told You Once, I've Told You 1,000,000,000 Times](http://books.google.com/books?id=yZOPSQAACAAJ&dq=once+%2B%22told+you%22+%2Btimes&hl=en&ei=kL_CTfypBYODtgezo9yyBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBA) - 2010
> - [If I've told you once, I've told you countless times](http://books.google.com/books?ei=Hr_CTe_2G4fAtgeK8_m-BQ&ct=result&id=XERfAAAAMAAJ&dq=once+%2B%22told+you+%2a+times%22&q=%22If+I%27ve+told+you+once%2C+I%27ve+told+you+countless+times%22#search_anchor) - 2002
> - [Dear Rocker in Constance: If I've told you pinheads once, I've told you a thousand times — anybody who listens to the Beatles in 1995 is not only living in the past, he's brain dead!](http://books.google.com/books?id=2fEDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA23&dq=once+%2B%22told+you%22+%2Btimes&hl=en&ei=kL_CTfypBYODtgezo9yyBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CEIQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22Dear%20Rocker%20in%20Constance%3A%20If%20I%27ve%20told%20you%20pinheads%20once%2C%20I%27ve%20told%20you%20a%20thousand%20times%20%E2%80%94%20anybody%20who%20listens%20to%20the%20Beatles%20in%201995%20is%20not%20only%20living%20in%20the%20past%2C%20he%27s%20brain%20dead!%22&f=false) - 1995
> - [I told you once, Hopkins, I told you million times](http://books.google.com/books?ei=-73CTaLBCYS6tgffjojIBQ&ct=result&id=9youAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22told%20you%22%20%2b%22told%20you%20%2a%20times%22&q=%22I%20told%20you%20once,%20Hopkins,%20I%20told%20you%20million%20times%22#search_anchor) - 194?
> - [If I've told you once I've told you five thousand times](http://books.google.com/books?ei=ea_CTfO-E8qBtge71_W8BQ&ct=result&id=3bBAAAAAIAAJ&dq=told%20once%20%22told%20you%20%2a%20%2a%20times%22&q=%22If%20I%27ve%20told%20you%20once%20I%27ve%20told%20you%20five%20thousand%20times%22#search_anchor) - 1941
> - [If I have told you once I have told you ten dozen times](http://books.google.com/books?ei=wcbCTfCaCoSgtweW0MmsBQ&ct=result&id=39oYAAAAYAAJ&dq=once%20%2b%22told%20you%22%20%2btimes&q=%22If%20I%20have%20told%20you%20once%20I%20have%20told%20you%20ten%20dozen%20times%22#search_anchor) - 1930
> - [If I've told you that once, I've told you thrice — I've told you a thousand times](http://books.google.com/books?id=fJ0OAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA282&dq=once%20%22told%20you%20%2a%20%2a%20times%22&hl=en&ei=Hr_ATciFLerm0QHwhYW3Cg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22If%20I%27ve%20told%20you%20that%20once,%20I%27ve%20told%20you%20thrice%20%E2%80%94%20I%27ve%20told%20you%20a%20thousand%20times%22&f=false) - ?1927?
> - [don't you know that I not only told you once but, in response to repeated importunities from you, that I told you several times](http://books.google.com/books?ei=-73CTaLBCYS6tgffjojIBQ&ct=result&id=WhAwAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22told+you%22+%2B%22told+you+%2a+times%22&q=%22don%27t+you+know+that+I+not+only+told+you+once+but%2C+in+response+to+repeated+importunities+from+you%2C+that+I+told+you+several+times%22#search_anchor) - 1919
> - [if I said to you once, don't touch confiscated property, I told you so ten thousand times](http://books.google.com/books?id=U6VNAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=inside%20a%20chronicle%20of%20secession&hl=en&ei=Gia_TeXgOMTh0QGc2ejRBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA#v=snippet&q=%22if%20I%20said%20to%20you%20once,%20don%27t%20touch%20confiscated%20property,%20I%20told%20you%20so%20ten%20thousand%20times%22&f=false) - 1866
> - [once is as good as if I had told you a thousand Times over](http://books.google.com/books?ei=slG_Tc7uE4G08QOK_4TJBQ&ct=result&output=text&id=JXxEAAAAcAAJ&dq=%22told%20you%20a%20thousand%22&q=%22once%20is%20as%20good%20as%20if%20I%20had%20told%20you%20a%20thousand%20Times%20over%22#v=snippet&q=%22once%20is%20as%20good%20as%20if%20I%20had%20told%20you%20a%20thousand%20Times%20over%22&f=false) - 1735

As a @FumbleFinger's once said:

**It's just a standard speech device that people reinvent repeatedly**

Comment: Allowed. Here's much the same construction printed 1730, reporting usage in 1649... http://books.google.com/books?id=JXxEAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA201&dq=%22told+you+a+thousand%22&hl=en&ei=slG_Tc7uE4G08QOK_4TJBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CFUQ6AEwBzgK#v=onepage&q=%22told%20you%20a%20thousand%22&f=false

Comment: @Fumble: You beat me to it! I was going to report on that find. So, does this mean you are "inquiring into its origins" after all?

Comment: @Callithumpian: Damn you, sirrah! I am outed as a closet etymologist!

Comment: Good response, but I can't call it an answer. Maybe FumbleFingers is right, and there is no answer, but the chosen answer to [Origin of "he's 6 feet tall if he's an inch"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14216/origin-of-hes-6-feet-tall-if-hes-an-inch) does an excellent job of describing how this kind of rhetorical hyperbole ends up getting formulated in language. But I still don't know what to do with this question.

Comment: @kojiro as I said in the question, I don't think this is a duplicate at all - it's almost unrelated. You're asking about an origin of something that is almost sure to have no origin because it is way too standard. Anyone can come up with that, easily. To prove my point, I hope turning the answer into a CW and asking for contributions can make it big enough over time. ;)

Comment: The cite mentioned by @FumbleFingers also provides a more full gloss as to the meaning of it: "I must tell you again, and once is as good as if I had told you a thousand times over..."